# Broken / combined colormaps

Tags: colors, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting a 2D scalar field with imshow, and I'd like to clearly contrast negative values from positive ones.  Is there a way to implement a colormap composed of two others (e.g. jet for example, `hot` for positive and `cool` for negative)?

Answer (score 3):

You can read the colors from the existing cmaps and just add them, thats fairly simple but has as few drawbacks. If the original colormaps have a different number of colors, the 'edge' of both will not be centered.

If they do have the same number, the resulting cmap will be symmetric, but the 'edge' will only be at zero if the positive value equals the negative value, eg -2 & 2 or -4 & 4, etc.

This can be done like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cool = plt.cm.cool
hot = plt.cm.hot

cool_vals = [cool(i) for i in range(cool.N)]
hot_vals = [hot(i) for i in range(hot.N)]

comb_vals = cool_vals + hot_vals

# random hue with constant sat and value
new_cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(comb_vals)

plt.imshow(np.arange(20*20).reshape(20,20)-199., interpolation='none', cmap=new_cmap)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Im not aware of very fancy methods in Matplotlib. There is a brand new Python module '[TrollImage](http://trollimage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/colormap.html)' which has a really nice implementation of working with colormaps. Its aimed at satellite images but the colormap part of course applies to any kind of image.